# React .map is not a function on array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, dictionary

I'm trying to get all products from my api.
Code of API forproducts is below. 
Code below is working well:

```
const heh = () => {
        products.map((p) => console.log(p.id))
    }
```

The problem is that products.map in my `const allProducts` telling me `TypeError: products.map is not a function`.
P.S. I've checked **all types**. I'm getting **array of Objects**.
Full code below:

```js
const Product = ({products}) => {
    const heh = () => {
        products.map((p) => console.log(p.id))
    }
    const allProducts = products.map((p) => (
        <div className="product" key={p.id}>
            <h3>{p.name} - {p.price}</h3>
            <p>{p.description}</p>
        </div>)
        )
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => heh()}>Click</button>
            {allProducts}
        </div>
        
    )
}


const Test = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchProducts = async () => {
            const result = await axios('/api/v1/products')
            console.log(result.data.data)
            setProducts(result.data)
        }

        fetchProducts()
        
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Product products={products} />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Test), document.getElementById('app'))
```

TS:

```
const result = await client.query("SELECT * FROM products")
        const products = new Array()

        result.rows.map(p => {
            let obj: any = new Object()
            result.rowDescription.columns.map((el, i) => {
                obj[el.name] = p[i]
            })

            products.push(obj)
        })

        response.body = {
            success: true,
            data: products
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you've checked the types *at the right time*? I'd suggest either setting a debugger breakpoint on the `const allProducts = products.map((p) => (` line and examining the value of `products` when the program pauses there, or adding `console.log("products:", products)` just before that line.

Comment: `React.useState(0)`, start as a number, you expect it to be an array. What? I mean `useEffect` is doing stuff after rendering, your `fetch` is async, that's two reasons why your default value would matter?

Comment: in your test you are doing `console.log(result.data.data)` but then you are passing `result.data` to the function `setProducts`. Are you sure you there is no nested variable called `data` where the inner `data` is the array of products.

Comment: products initialize with number (0) then you assigned a array, so it should be `const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial state for `products` is `0`. That means when you pass it to `Product` for the first time, it will be a number, not an array. Numbers don't have a `map` function, so you'll get an error.

If `products` will be an array, use `[]` as its initial state:

```
const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

...or a flag value like `null` that you check before trying to use `map`.

---

Side note: You're using `map` incorrectly. If you're not returning a value from the `map` callback, and not using the new array `map` creates, you shouldn't use `map`. Use `forEach` or a simple loop.

Comment: Yep.You was right. Something happens with my application for some reasons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you instead try this:

```
return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => heh()}>Click</button>
            {products.map((p) => (
        return (<div className="product" key={p.id}>
            <h3>{p.name} - {p.price}</h3>
            <p>{p.description}</p>
        </div>))}
        </div>
        
    )
```

Comment: same problem. I knew about it and it was my first option :(

Comment: as suggested by others make it `const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])`

Comment: you are doing a console.log of `result.data.data` but storing inside products `result.data` can that cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

When your `heh` function executed, the products list have been loaded and it is an array.

You got the error on line `const allProducts = ...` because you set the default value of products is a number. In this line

`const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(0)`

Replace with an empty array as default will solve your problem:

`const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])`

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you initialize the state of the products prop with 0, which is not an iterable object. Initialize it with useState([]).

Answer (score 0):

When you typed the question title, you should've identified your problem right away -

> React `.map` is not a function on array of objects

You *think* you have an array of objects. But if you don't have `.map` to call on it, then you don't have an array. Really, it's as simple as that.

Comment: no!!! who taught you to write code like that? you are using `.map` wrong in _two_ ways: 1) as `.forEach` and 2) as `.reduce`. A more proper use is `response.body = { success: true, products: results.rows.map(row => result.rowDescription.columns.reduce((r, col, i) => Object.assign(r, { [col.name]: row[i] }), {}))`